# python networkx allow duplicate nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to look at 3 columns and create a iterative tree list.

[image]

I want to iterate through to the top till I find null parent code and show the full tree view.

Code I am using:

```
df = df.fillna('null')
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(zip(df['ChildCode'],df['parentCode'] ))
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=df.set_index('ChildCode')['ChildOrg'].to_dict())
```

My relabeling of nodes is removing duplicate values i.e. finance and hence the result is a bit off. If there  a way I can allow duplicate nodes while relabelling?.

The result I get is not able to recognise duplicate childorg entries and assigns all to the same parent code for some reason.

[image]

**I am expecting the result like below:**

[image]

Comment: You do not have `df['null']` in your example. Please provide a sample of the real dataframe that matches your code.

Comment: Updated question with details

Answer (score 1):

If `df['null']` contains numbers, then they are not subscriptable. For example, `123456[1:3]` would raise the same error. I guess you want the following code:

```
df['Path'] = df['null'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(str(x)[-2::-1]))
```

Another potential problem is filling out the missing values by 'null'. Do you want 'un' to be returned in this case? If not, please treat these values separately. For example,

```
df['Path'] = df['null'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(str(x)[-2::-1]) if x != 'null' else 'null')
```

Comment: This code breaks the name stings into something strange '/l/l/u/n/'/ /,/'/y/e/l/l/e/h/S/ /a/c/c/e/b/e/R/'/[

Comment: Oh, sorry. The reason is that the string contains '. Is there any chance that " is not possible inside the string?